# Mongoose connection closing after updating node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am updating packages from an old project, as well as Node. I've updated from node 12 to node 18, 2 versions at a time, and production seems to be running fine, but in my development environment, I'm randomly getting this error:

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongooseserverselectionerror-connect-econnrefused-127-0-0-1-27017/123421).

All I had to do was replace my connection URL `mongodb://localhost:27017/myDB` by `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB`, and it started working normally again